# Pass arguments to ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to `Angular`, and I have this simple form:

```
<form ng-submit="add()">
  <input type="text" name="field">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'd like to have `input[name="field"]` value as a parameter of `add()`. Is there any way to do that?

What I did so far is to assign `ng-model="field"` in the input and within `add()` look for `$scope.field`.

In the controller I have an array of items, and the `add()` function. The `$scope.field` is hanging around like an intermediate step to get the value of the input to `add()` that I shouldn'd need.

Am I missing something or is this Angular's way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would modify TheHippo's answer a bit and pass `field` as an argument to `add()`. This is more of a code design choice, but I think it lends to more flexibility and better testing.

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyFormController">
  <form ng-submit="add(field)">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
   scope.add = function(field) { // <-- here is you value from the input 
     // ...
   };
}]);
```

And a little note:
If you follow most AngularJS tutorials online where there is some list being managed, and new items are added to that list, you will almost always see one of these properties that tend to "hang around" (they're often named 'newItem' etc.). In a way, this *is* the AngularJS way :)

Comment: This still binds the input value to `scope.field`.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not quite sure how it differs from your solution in that regard.

Comment: I like this approach the most.

Comment: @jlb You save a line of code, but you pollute the scope the same way other answers do.

Comment: @TheHippo I do agree that this adds something that some might say is superfluous to the scope, but this approach is quite a common solution in the AngularJS world

Comment: @jib are you passing the name of the input field or the ng-model of the input field.... Can we have the same name in many input fields?

Comment: @NivasDhina the part in my example `add(field)` is passing the object bound to the ng-model. Having the same name on many input fields is not recommended.

Answer (score 13):

Make a small change to you HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="add()">
  <input type="text" name="field" model="field">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the controller (/ directive) that holds the form:

```
app.controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
   scope.add = function() {
     scope.field // <-- here is you value from the input 
   };
}]);
```

This is the easiest and intended way you can do this in angular.

You could start looking into writing a own directive / service that will do what you want to archive, but depending of the rest of you code, this might be the easiest and shortest way.

Comment: the field is bind to the `model` or `name` ?

Comment: @Sekai It is bound to the model.

Answer (score 6):

This is how it is done:

form.html

```
<form ng-submit="create(product)">
    <input ng-model="product.name" class="u-full-width" type="text" id="name">
    <input ng-model="product.price" class="u-full-width" type="number" id="price">
    <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('productCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.create = function(product){
        console.log(product)
    };
})
```

Comment: @Julio how can I get the ID of submit button with type=submit, if it has an ID ?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say it's Angular's way, but it is how it goes, and I think cleaner that what I'm about to tell you.

You can use the [form directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform), and pass the value of the input to to your `add` method.  Unfortunately ngForm requires you use ngModel, so it's kind of a wash.

http://jsfiddle.net/unsWy/

```
<div ng-app>
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="add(myForm.field.$viewValue)" ng-controller="x">
        <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="field" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

`ngForm` works off of the field names, not your model properties, so if you wanted to, you could get creative with the `ngModel` directive on your inputs and hide them away so they're not "in your way" so to speak:

```
<input type="text" name="field" ng-model="$$ignore.field" required>
```

That said, you're probably better off just using $scope as intended. :)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyFormController">
  <form ng-submit="add(field)">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function MyFormController($scope) {
   $scope.add= function(field) {
      alert(field)
   }
}
</script>
```

Note: if 'field' is a string use quotes ng-submit="add('field')"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why. But I have to use 'this' to make it work.

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyFormController">
  <form ng-submit="add()">
    <input type="text" name="field" ng-model="field" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('MyFormController', ['$scope', function(scope) {
   scope.add = function() { 
     console.log(this.field) // <-- this works for me
   };
}]);
```

Answer (score -2):

alert(document.getElementById("bar").value); in controller
these things work for me thnks
    in view->html 
work form me